# Using multiple onClick methods in a single interface for RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, oop, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

**Context:**

I've implemented a RecyclerView in my to-do list app.

I wanted to be able to use various onClick methods for items within the RecyclerView so I created an interface called onTaskListener.

This interface has two method stubs, one for onClick and one for onLongClick. In my ViewHolder, I implement both the onClick() and onLongClick() methods which simply pass off control to my onTaskClickListener().

In my adapter, I create an onTaskClickListener().
Then in my main activity, I implement the methods within onTaskClickListener().

*My issue is that while my onTaskClick() works perfectly, my onTaskLongClick doesn't seem to function at all. Is there something wrong with the way I set up my RecyclerView/Adapter/ViewHolder/ViewModel pattern?*

**Question:** If the way I have implemented my interface is wrong, how do I include multiple types of click events within a single interface?

Here are the relevant contents of each file (I know it's a lot, I'm very sorry for the wall of code):

**onTaskClickListener.java:**

```
public interface OnTaskListener {
    void onTaskClick(int position); // Interfaces are implicitly abstract
    void onTaskLongClick(int position);
}
```

**itemViewHolder.java:**

```
public class itemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    View itmView; // This is the general view
    TextView txtView; // This is the specific text view that shows up as a singular task in the list of to-do tasks
    OnTaskListener onTaskListener; // Create an OnTaskListener inside our view holder which allows the view holder to realize it's been clicked

    public itemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnTaskListener inputOnTaskListener) {
        super(itemView);
        itmView = itemView;
        txtView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTask);
        this.onTaskListener = inputOnTaskListener; // Take an onTaskListener that is passed into the object and store it internally
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // passes the View.OnClickListener context to the itemView via "this"
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onTaskListener.onTaskClick(getAdapterPosition()); // This says that whenever we register a click event, we pass the logic onto the taskClick event
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        onTaskListener.onTaskLongClick(getAdapterPosition()); // This says that whenever we register a longClick event, we pass the logic onto the taskClick event
        return true; // This means that we have successfully consumed the long click event. No other click events will be notified
    }
}
```

**dataAdapter.java**

```
public class dataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<itemViewHolder> {

    List<taskItem> taskItemList;
    private OnTaskListener onTaskListener;

    public dataAdapter(List<taskItem> inputTaskItemList, OnTaskListener inputOnTaskListener){
        this.taskItemList = inputTaskItemList;
        this.onTaskListener = inputOnTaskListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public itemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View localView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.taskholder, parent, false); //Don't even know what this line does, it's all so over my head
        return new itemViewHolder(localView, onTaskListener); // Return an instance of whatever we made directly above this line
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull itemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txtView.setText(taskItemList.get(position).taskTitle);
        // Look inside our ViewModel and get the text for this specific instance of the ViewModel, which corresponds to the current position
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return taskItemList.size();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTaskListener{
    private RecyclerView taskList; // Creates a RecyclerView to hook up to our RecyclerView widget in the UI
    private dataAdapter localAdapter; // Instantiates our custom adapter class
    List<taskItem> myItems; // Stores the items in a list of taskItem's
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager localLayoutManager; // God knows what this does :(

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        taskList = findViewById(R.id.taskList); // Connects our list from UI to recycler view code
        localLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); // assigns our localLayoutManager to an actual Layout Manager
        taskList.setLayoutManager(localLayoutManager); // connecting our layout manager to our recycler view
        taskList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        myItems = new ArrayList<>(); // Now we FINALLY make our to-do list and populate it with actual tasks
        myItems.add(new taskItem("groceries"));
        myItems.add(new taskItem("practice bjj"));

        localAdapter = new dataAdapter(myItems, this); // Pass the to do list to the adapter so it can feed it to the recycler view
        taskList.setAdapter(localAdapter); // Lastly set the recycler view's adapter to the one we made above
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskClick(int position) {
        taskItem currentTask = myItems.get(position);
        if(!(currentTask.taskTitle.startsWith("Done: "))){ // Logic that marks a task as done on tap
            currentTask.taskTitle = "Done: " + currentTask.taskTitle;
            //logic that moves the tapped item to bottom of list
            myItems.remove(position);
            myItems.add(myItems.size(), currentTask);
            localAdapter.notifyItemMoved(position, myItems.size());
        }
        else if(myItems.get(position).taskTitle.startsWith("Done: ")){ // Logic for if user taps a task already marked "done"
            currentTask.taskTitle = currentTask.taskTitle.replaceFirst("Done: ", "");
            myItems.set(position, currentTask); // Remove prefix
            localAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            myItems.remove(position);
            myItems.add(0, currentTask);
        }
        localAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Let the activity know that the data has changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskLongClick(int position) { // This branch deals with deleting tasks on long click
        myItems.remove(position);
        localAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position); // Item has been deleted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never call [`setOnLongClickListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)):

```
public itemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnTaskListener inputOnTaskListener) {
    super(itemView);
    itmView = itemView;
    txtView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTask);
    this.onTaskListener = inputOnTaskListener; // Take an onTaskListener that is passed into the object and store it internally
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // passes the View.OnClickListener context to the itemView via "this"

    // Add this line
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this); // passes the View.OnLongClickListener context to the itemView via "this"
}
```

Alternatively, you can avoid going through `this` entirely by inlining the entire `OnLongClickListener` (and similarly for the `OnClickListener`):

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        onTaskListener.onTaskLongClick(getAdapterPosition()); // This says that whenever we register a longClick event, we pass the logic onto the taskClick event
        return true; // This means that we have successfully consumed the long click event. No other click events will be notified
    }
 });
```

Thus avoiding having your `itemViewHolder` class implement the `OnLongClickListener` interface and making it impossible to forget to call `setOnLongClickListener()`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Thank you. Is there any way I can make Android Studio warn me if this happens? Or is this just a matter of being careful?

Comment: It is much more common to pass in an `OnClickListener` implementation directly to the `setOnClickListener()` method, rather than passing in `this`. That way the setting of the listener and the listener itself aren't decoupled as they are in your code.

Comment: Wouldn't that move the implementation of my onclicklistener into my view holder though? Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought that was considered bad practice?

Comment: The anonymous `OnClickListener` you'd pass to `setOnClickListener` would still call your  `onTaskClick`, just like it does now. You just wouldn't redirect through `this`.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry but I have never done that before. Would you mind showing me how it would look if done that way?

Comment: I added an example of what that would look like in my answer.

Comment: Awesome thank you, it worked perfectly. Only thing is that I had to remember to get rid of the "implements..." statement in the class definition because I no longer directly implement those methods.